# How to rewrite any subpath of a folder to a specific index.html file in .htaccess

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, url-rewriting, joomla

I have an apache server with a joomla installation in the root directory. Now i want to host a React.js app with react router in a subdirectory /react. This app has different views on different subpaths and also pulls information from the url parameters, so i basically need to rewrite any url with the pattern `%ROOT%/react/*` to `/react/index.html`
How can i do that? I already tried multiple variations of

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /react/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /react/index.html [L]`

but without success. Any ideas?

Comment: "with react router in a subdirectory `/react`" - and this "react router" is what you have posted here? You shouldn't need to anything particularly special for this to work - please post the entire contents of `/react/.htaccess`.

Comment: you are right, this actually works. my mistake was that i added these lines to the .htaccess file in my server's root dir instead of creating a new one in the /react directory. Also, i had to prepend the routes in react router with "/react" for it to work properly.